# ASP:Imagemap making the hotspots easily findable

Tags: asp.net, css, imagemap

I  am developing a application that would benefit from identifying items from an image map. 
You can create image maps easily on a asp.net site using this code.

```
<asp:imagemap id="ImageMap1" runat="server" imageurl="image.gif">
<asp:circleHotSpot PostbackValue="Area1" radius="10" X="30" Y="30" ALternateText="Area1" HotSpotMode="PostBack">
</asp:imagemap>
```

You could change the image to show the hot spots location but it would be easier in this case to show the hot spot with a mouse over or border.

If you look at facebook when people are identified in an image this is kind of what I am trying to achieve any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ImageMaps are pretty limited. Not sure exactly how facebook does it, but when I have to do imagemap-like functionality these days, I tend to use a  with the background image then appropriately sized and absolutely positioned images overlaid on the DIV. Then you can use most of our neat CSS tricks to do stuff like add borders, have relatively positioned popups, etc.

Comment: This could work for me i would then have to use some java script to identify where the user would like the hotspots to go.